# Changes to Freestyle in Blender 4.0

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I recently changed to blender 4.0.2 from 3.something and i have noticed that my setup for freestyle outlines is behaving differently.

It now outlines decals (which i set up as a separate mesh which is hovering over the shirt with a transparent texture), which it did not do before.
changing between Edge Type of Silhouette or Crease does not seem to change anything and i tried manually setting the outside of the decal as a Marked Edge to be excluded but that just causes blender to crash on rendering.

Any advice on how to keep freestyle from not rendering the outside of the decals?

[image: The decal on the shirt is outlined by freestyle]